# Big O notation for these algorithm complexities

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have a few algorithm complexities that I'm not entirely sure of what the Big O notations are for them.

i) ((n-1)(n-1) * ... * 2 * 1)/2

ii) 56 + 2n + n^2 + 3n^3

iii) 2n(lg n) + 1001

iv) n^2 * n^3 + 2^n

I believe  ii) and iii) are pretty straightforward with the Big O of ii) being O(n^3) and the Big O of iii) being O(n log n) but let me know if these are wrong.

It's mostly i) and iv) I'm a bit confused on. For i) I assumed it followed the same idea as 1+2+3+4+...+n which has a Big O notation of O(n^2) so that's what I put and for iv) I put O(n^5) but I'm not sure if the 2^n affects the Big O notation in this case, I'm not sure what gets priority here or do I just include them both?

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm not that experienced in Big O notation so any advice would be really helpful as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `i)` supposed to be adding the terms or multiplying them?

Comment: @BilltheLizard multiplying, sorry if it's not clear. I can make an edit if you think it will help

Comment: Replying to you actually just made me realize that my logic for i) is flawed, they aren't being added so the reasoning behind it being O(n^2) doesn't apply here. I think it could be something to the power of n or (n-1) but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since problem i) is multiplying (not adding) the terms from 1 to n, that should be O(n!).

You're right on ii) n^3 is the dominant term, so it's O(n^3), and on iii) both constants 2 and 1001 can be ignored leaving you with O(n log n).

On iv) you were right to combine the first two terms to get n^5, but even that will eventually be surpassed by the 2^n term, so the answer is O(2^n).

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks a lot. So, in general, say 'x' is any integer then x^n will always dominate n^x?

Comment: @Maximus In terms of complexity analysis, yes. The 'x' values tend to be very small, mostly based on how nested your loops or recursive calls are, while the 'n' values in these problems represent the size of the input, which can be very large. It's better to have your 'n' variable in the base than in the exponent.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help